# How to fix "Test source folder in project must have an output folder that is not also used for main resources"?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a gradle project running in eclipse and just upgraded from gradle 4 to gradle 6. Now, if i do a "gradle refresh" i get the error "Test source folder 'src/integration-test/java' in project ... must have an output folder that is not also used for main resources".

i checked my .classpath file and the output folder for the source folder IS different from the main resources.

Here's the classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test,integrationTest"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test,integrationTest"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test,integrationTest"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/integrationTest" path="src/integration-test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/integrationTest" path="src/integration-test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/default"/>
</classpath>
```

I also tried to change the output folders to just some random ones, but i still got the error.
Am i understanding the error incorrectly? Can some gradle setting cause this?

The stacktrace of the error looks like this btw:

```
Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an unexpected error.
Test source folder 'src/integration-test/java' in project 'impl' must have an output folder that is not also used for main sources
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Test source folder 'src/integration-test/java' in project 'impl' must have an output folder that is not also used for main sources]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:795)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:3530)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:3490)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:3546)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SourceFolderUpdater.updateSourceFolders(SourceFolderUpdater.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SourceFolderUpdater.update(SourceFolderUpdater.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeJavaProjectInTransaction(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.access$200(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation$4.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5733)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5690)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeJavaProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeOpenWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeGradleProjectWithWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.access$000(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation$1.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2311)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeProjectsWithWorkspace(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
```

Comment: Which Eclipse and Buildship versions do you have? Do you get this issue also with a single test output folder instead of the two, `bin/test` and `bin/integrationTest`?

Comment: Show gradle configuration.

Comment: i use Eclipse 4.8 and Gradle 6.6.

Comment: and yaeh, same problem with a single output folder.(changed it in eclipse settings)

Comment: Eclipse 4.8 is pretty old (9 releases behind), much older than Gradle 6.6. So this might be caused by using outdated software in combination with newer software.

Comment: Could you share the source tab from the Java Build Path screen of your project ?

Comment: Also @tangens, could you share the relevant part of your gradle conf, like the `sourceSets` definition ?

Comment: I tried to extract the relevant source pathes, but I didn't succeed. I use a selfmade gradle plugin that creates the needed sourcePathes itself. gradle has no problems with this, only eclipse complains about this. When I declare these source pathes explicitly, everything works fine. So I have no idea how to narrow this down.

Comment: @tangens Sure, Gradle can compile everything into the same output folder. But when using Eclipse that has its own incremental Java compiler (which by default compiles files incrementally on save, which Gradle and Maven are not able to do), different output folders for main and test are required since both have different dependencies. Did you take care of that in your self made Gradle build? Please note, you put a bounty on maybe unrelated question where someone just missed updating Eclipse for a very long time, which you hopefully didn't, right?

Comment: @howlger Yes, I'm using an actual version of gradle (6.8.2) and eclipse (2020.06). For each type (main, test, testFixtures) of sourcePath I have configurest a different outputPath. Most of the times I have more than one sourcePath for one type (main-handmade, main-generated, test-handmade, test-generated, testFixture-handmade, testFixture-generated).

Comment: @tangens Please show your Gradle build file and what you have in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Source_ with expanded tree (so that the _Output folder_ nodes are visible). Eclipse 2020-06 is one release behind. If you upgraded to this version, please tell also the Buildship version you use.

Comment: without a context, it's impossible to help you, there is many things that can interfere here (my money is one this  selfmade gradle plugin). We need data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/integrationTest" path="src/integration-test/java">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
        <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/integrationTest" path="src/integration-test/resources">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
        <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Where `output="bin/integrationTest"` it's being used on both output, so you could add another output instead, something like:

```
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/integrationTest/java" path="src/integration-test/java">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
        <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/integrationTest/resources" path="src/integration-test/resources">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
        <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="integrationTest"/>
        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```